# No member named 'forward' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, compiler-errors

In XCode, I recently made and tested a processing library that uses boost. I just set up a basic project in the IDE, coded away, and it builds fine.

I now want to use that library in another application. The other application's xcode project was automatically made using a 3rd party tool. When I try to include my boost-based library in this other application, I get errors stating . . .

`No member named 'forward' in namespace 'std'`

and also, the line . .

```
#include <tuple>
```

gives the preprocessor error

`'tuple' file not found`

Seeing as the original library builds just fine on my machine, the errors must be down to a difference in the build settings, but I cannot see the difference and do not know of a good way to compare the build settings of 2 different projects. Can anyone suggest the build setting that might be causing me the problem??

**EDIT:**

In both projects, the setting for

- Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C = Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0
- C++ Language dialect = Compiler default
- C++ Standard Library = Compiler default

**EDIT 2 [solved]:**

- I still had C++11 dialect enabled in the Target settings. DoH!

Comment: Have you installed the "command line utilities" from the Downloads tab in XCode's preferences? For some reason, a lot of C++ stuff doesn't seem to come with the default XCode install anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project compiles as C++11 and is using a C++11 standard library (std::forward and the  header are new).
The original project appears to compile as C++03 with a C++03 standard library, so those new features are not available.

Comment: I have checked the language / library settings and they seem identical (see edit). Is there another setting that I am missing?