# Xcode QuantLib building error: loses integer precision and no template named 'forward'

Tags: c++, xcode, quantlib

I'm writing C++ with Xcode 7.2.1 and want to use QuantLib 1.7.1. I installed the package following the instructions on quantlib.org and changed project settings according to this essay

https://www.scribd.com/doc/210157027/QuantLib-1-4-Xcode-4-5-2#

But when I build the project, there are always two types of errors:

```
Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'Day' (aka 'int')

No template named 'forward' in namespace 'std'; did you mean simply 'forward'?
```

I tried to use QuantLib 1.6.2, but the problem remained the same. How can I solve these problems?

Update:

Second problem solved. Only two types of first problem remained: loses integer precision and unused variable issue. Here is a snapshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKbLH.jpg

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10948355/862288) help?

Comment: @BobJansen Thanks! It solved the second problem. Now i only need to deal with the first one.

Comment: Those are just warnings right?  Not on XCode but I think some warnings are expected.

Comment: @BobJansen yep, but it stops the code. I'm wondering if there is a way to solve this problem or discard it, so that it will not prevent the code from running.

Comment: As warnings, those shouldn't stop the build unless you have some setting telling the IDE to treat them as error (as the `-Werror` flag does from the command line). May you check for such a setting?